# `brew upgrade` hangs on El Capitan

Tags: homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I can't run `brew upgrade` without it hanging indefinitely. I'm using El Capitan OS. Here's the input/output:

```
>>$ brew upgrade
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core, homebrew/science).
==> Updated Formulae
artifactory         dovecot             node@4              scamper
chromedriver        node-build          openvpn
==> Deleted Formulae
pdksh

==> Upgrading 10 outdated packages, with result:
gcc 6.2.0, gdbm 1.12, libtiff 4.0.7, openssl 1.0.2j, pkg-config 0.29.1_2, python 2.7.12_2, homebrew/science/r 3.3.2, readline 7.0.1, sqlite 3.15.2, yara 3.5.0_1
==> Upgrading gcc
Warning: Building gcc from source:
  The bottle needs the Xcode CLT to be installed.
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/gcc-6.2.0/gcc-6.2.0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Users/r8t/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc-6.2.0.tar.bz2
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/e9e0e
Already downloaded: /Users/r8t/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc--patch-863957f90a934ee8f89707980473769cff47ca0663c3906992da6afb242fb220.patch
==> Patching
==> Applying 6.1.0-jit.patch
patching file gcc/jit/Make-lang.in
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gc
==> make bootstrap
```

And then nothing.

Comment: Have you tried to install xcode CLT?

Comment: Ha, I just started it running before you wrote that :P

Comment: is this the first time you are installing home brew on your machine?

Comment: No, I've had it forever, but likely the first upgrade or update since El Capitan.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

- `ctrl + c` to exit the hanging upgrade.
- Run `brew doctor`.  It prompted me to
- run `brew cleanup` to clean up false symlinks.  Then I
- ran `brew doctor` again and  it prompted me
- to install xcode CLT via
  the command `sudo xcode-select --install`.
- Finally `brew update`
  worked.

Comment: The `xcode-select --install` fixed the hanging GCC make for me. Thanks!

Comment: All I did was `brew doctor` then `brew prune`. Not sure why that solved it. I'm on High Sierra 10.13.2

Comment: Ctrl+c did not exit the hang

Comment: `brew prune` has been replaced with `brew cleanup`

Answer (score 89):

It could be downloading something large and taking a long time. Try running the following so you can see the download progress:

```
brew update --debug --verbose
```

Comment: After doing that I got this: Another active Homebrew update process is already in progress.Please wait for it to finish or terminate it to continue. How do you know when "Another" is done?

Comment: `brew update --verbose` might be enough as `--debug` is quite confusing (e.g. verbose made it easy to see I had too many taps and it was blocking on one)

Comment: This was helpful as I was able to see it was actually doing something.

Comment: `brew update-reset` fixed it for me — it is very slow though, patience is necessary.

Comment: @NateLevin not all heroes wear capes. Thank you very much! you saved me!

Comment: After running `brew update --verbose` I was able to see that the process was still running correctly. However, my mac would always go to sleep. Running [keepingyouawake.app](https://keepingyouawake.app/) fixed this for me (also available via `brew`).

Answer (score 27):

Verbose mode does work for me:

```
brew update --verbose
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answer of @travelingbones, installation of `gcc` gets stuck when you do perform `brew upgrade`. You can further verify it by running this command

**Verification of problem**

```
brew install gcc
```

Instead of this, Doing following, speeds up the process, as brew installs **precompiled** version of gcc after x-code installation

**Do this instead**

```
sudo xcode-select --install
brew install gcc
```